# Python Frequency filtering with seemingly wrong frequencies

Tags: python, scipy, fft, frequency

The script below filters frequencies by cutting of all frequencies larger than 6.
However instead of using the seemingly correct function `rfftfreq`, `fftfreq` is being used.

To my understandnig `rfftfreq` should be used together with `rfft`. Why does this code work although it uses `fftfreq` with `rfft`?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft, fftfreq

time   = np.linspace(0,10,2000)
signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time) + np.cos(7*np.pi*time)

W = fftfreq(signal.size, d=time[1]-time[0])
f_signal = rfft(signal)

# If our original signal time was in seconds, this is now in Hz    
cut_f_signal = f_signal.copy()
cut_f_signal[(W<6)] = 0

cut_signal = irfft(cut_f_signal)
```

Background: `rfft` gives an array sorting the fourier modes with real and imaginery in separate entries. Such as `[R(0), R(1), I(1), ... R(N/2),I(N/2)]` for `R(n)` and `I(n)` being the real and imaginery part of the fourier mode respectively. (assuming an even entry array)

Therefore, `rfftfreq` yields an array of frequencies corresponding to this array  such as (assuming an even entry array and sampling spacing of 1):

```
[0, 1/n, 1/n, 2/n, 2/n ... n/(2n), n/(2n)]
```

However this code works with `fftfreq` where the output of the function is

```
[0, 1/n, ... n/(2n), -n/(2n), ..., -1/n]
```

Clearly, `fftfreq` should lead to wrong results when used together with `rfft` because the frequencies and FFT bins do not match.

Comment: does this work? Does it do what it is supposed to?  What is the question?

Comment: It works, but it shouldnt imo...Therefore question: why does it work?

Comment: If it works and you think it should not, maybe you have a misunderstanding.  Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: sorry, but whats wrong with a simple question starting with why!? Im not asking for a discussion neither for a tutorial. Just a straight answer why it works with fftfreq but not with rfftfreq.

Comment: @dann nothing wrong in principle. People get frustrated from many bad questions, and an opening statement like *I have found the following script...* is due to trigger bad feelings ;)

Comment: I think the question was stated clearly enough, with additional information demonstrating knowledge of the topic. I have applied some editing to make it more accessible.

Comment: The question could be further improved by stating how you determine that the code works with one function and not with the other, and what results you would expect instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis-specified the frequencies in the original signal.

A sine wave is parameterized according to this equation (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave)):
[image]

The factor **2**  is missing in the definition of `signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time) + np.cos(7*np.pi*time)`. Therefore, the actual frequencies are

```
5*pi*t = 2*pi*t * f
f = (5*pi*t) / (2*pi*t) = 5 / 2

7*pi*t = 2*pi*t * f
f = (7*pi*t) / (2*pi*t) = 7 / 2
```

In words, the two frequencies are half of what you think they are. Ironically, that is why it seems to work with `fftfreq` instead of `rfftfreq`. The former covers twice the frequency range (positive and negative frequencies), and therefore compensates for the missing factor 2.

This is the correct code:

```
signal = np.cos(5 * 2*np.pi * time) + np.cos(7 * 2*np.pi * time)
W = rfftfreq(signal.size, d=time[1]-time[0])
```